# Django: what is the most appropriate way to provide administrators with the ability to change small snippets of text

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Using Django, what is the most appropriate way to provide administrators with the ability to change small snippets of text, for example in one of my sites there is a small piece of text on the front page I would like the administrator to be able to easily change in the backend, however I do not want to create a whole new app or model because then they would be able to create more than one area of text in this way, but I only want it to show up in one place on the homepage.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit more than you're looking for, but [django-chunks](https://github.com/clintecker/django-chunks) lets you embed snippets of text into your templates and allow administrators to edit them. Because the only way to put a chunk into a template is by embedding it yourself, you don't have to worry about someone creating additional chunks - they just won't show up anywhere on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new setting in the settings file (or if you're using something like Djblets, in the appropriate model [or if you're using something else, wherever it expects settings to be]) for it, and then use it in the template after passing the appropriate context.

Comment: @Andrew: You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: I would not want the administrator to have to access/edit the settings file to change it however, I would prefer if it could be done through the admin interface.

Comment: @Ignorancio: I keep using that word because most of your answers are.

Comment: @Andrew: There, I've treated the asker like an idiot. Are you comfortable now?